# I'm very confused about passing data between controller and view multiple times

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to get sub id's when user clicks to dropdown's selected item's and people told me I need to pass data between controller and view multiple times I find an ajax code to post that id to controller but it returns null.

Is this the correct way to do this?

My view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("PersonalAdı")
        </td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonalName)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.Label("Departman")</td>
        <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonalDepartment)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("IseGirisTarihi")</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IseGirisTarihi)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormDetail.Form)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FormDetail.FormId, 
          Model.FormViewList)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormDetail.CheckListType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
  model.FormDetail.CheckListTypeId, Model.checkLists, new 
 {@id="Selection", 
 @class = "drop-open" })
        <td><button onclick="">Bolum Ekle</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:40px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/open.js"></script>
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Add()
{
        FormDetailViewModel model = new FormDetailViewModel();

        foreach(Form item in formRep.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            FormList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.FormId.ToString(), Text = item.TeslimEden });
        }

        foreach(Item item in itemRep.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            İtemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.ItemId.ToString(), Text = item.ItemDesc });
        }

        foreach(CheckListType item in typeRep.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            TypeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.CheckListTypeId.ToString(), Text = item.CheckListType1 });
        }

        model.checkLists = TypeList;
        model.FormViewList = FormList;
        model.İtems = İtemList;

        return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public void Add(FormDetailViewModel model, FormCollection form, string data)
{
        Console.WriteLine(data);

        Personal personal = new Personal();
        personal.PersonalAdı = model.PersonalName;
        personal.PersonalDepartmanı = model.PersonalDepartment;
        personal.IseGırısTarihi = model.IseGirisTarihi;
        personal.PersonalId = personalRep.GetMaxId() + 1;

        model.FormDetail.PersonalId = personal.PersonalId;

        personalRep.Insert(personal);

        model.FormDetail.DetailId = fDetailRep.GetMaxId() + 1;

        fDetailRep.Insert(model.FormDetail);
}
```

jQuery code :

```
$('#Selection').on('change', function () {
    var info = {
        id: $('#Selection option:selected').text()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Add", "FormDetail")',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(info),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ajaxDisplay').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Data is being returned as `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDataById(int id) {
    //your logic
    ....
    //response - return data which is required in your ajax success.
    return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Js :

```
$('#Selection').on('change', function () {
var id = $('#Selection option:selected').text();

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetDataById", "FormDetail")',
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'id': id }, 
    success: function (result) {
        $('#ajaxDisplay').html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Should ı send the data to get controller or post controller when i send post model's elements return null

Comment: @Eralp Post method is ok but on dropdown change your are inserting that i am not able to understand. Where are you getting model data you are not passing in ajax? In above ajax you are passing only data parameter that will bind data to only data parameter in controller and your model will be null.

Comment: I need to get selecteditem's id which is checkListTypeId .Im loading data in controller with get.Shoult ı create second get method to get that ı id and return it to view

Comment: @ yes create action which return you data based on id your passing.